# Splitting shapefile based on part of field in attribute table using ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, shapefile, field-calculator, error-000539

I'm new to Python and I need a script that can split my huge shapefile based on a certain attribute.

SO what I have is a big shapefile (over 3M records) with a field named "NISCODE".
In this code are values ranging from 11001 to 73109. But only the first number of the value is important to me, that's the base on which the shapefile needs to be split on.
So I need 7 shapefiles; everything starting with 1, with 2,...
[image]

I know I'll probably need a for loop, but I don't know how to put it in my code correctly.
Here is what I have so far, this was just a test to see if I could already make a selection for the 1st part (everything starting with 1...), but already that fails.

```
# Import system modules
import arcpy
from arcpy import env
env.overwriteOutput="True"

# Set workspace
# setting the environment
workspacedir= r"C:\..."
env.workspace= workspacedir

shp = r"C:\....\Adp.shp"

r=arcpy.Exists("Adp.shp")
print r
### Make a layer from the feature class
arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management("Adp.shp", "Vl_lyr")
##
# Wselect only those that have id starting with 1
arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management("Vl_lyr", "NEW_SELECTION", ' "NISCODE" = 1* ')
##
# Write the selected features to a new featureclass
arcpy.CopyFeatures_management("Vl_lyr", "Vlaanderen_1.shp")
```

**EDIT:**

The new code looks now like this:`

```
# Import system modules
import arcpy
from arcpy import env
env.overwriteOutput="True"

# Set workspace
# setting the environment
workspacedir= r"C:\..."
env.workspace= workspacedir

shp = r"C:\...\Adp.shp"

arcpy.AddField_management(shp, "newNISCODE", "TEXT")

arcpy.CalculateField_management(shp, "newNISCODE", '"newNISCODE" = NISCODE[0]', "PYTHON")

list = []
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(fc, "newNICODE") as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        list.append(row)
num_list = sorted(set(list))

for i in range(1, len(num_list)):
    arcpy.Select_analysis(shp, "{}_shp".format(i), 'newNICODE = "{}"'.format(i))`
```

but the code fails on the Calculatefield step:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\...\SplitShape.py", line 15, in <module>
    arcpy.CalculateField_management(shp, "newNISCODE", '"newNISCODE" = NISCODE[0]', "PYTHON")
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.5\ArcPy\arcpy\management.py", line 3663, in CalculateField
    raise e
ExecuteError: ERROR 000539: SyntaxError: invalid syntax (<expression>, line 1)
Failed to execute (CalculateField).
```

Comment: Please paste the code as text not as an image.

Comment: If it is not priority for you to write the script, maybe you could use field calculator to leave just the first number in "NISCODE" (which you need), and then do a split by attribute tool.

Comment: Sorry, I pasted the code now as text.

@Dean7 I do need to write a script for this.

Answer (score 2):

you don't need to compute a new field. In your code, the first problem is that you handle the NISCODE field as a numeric field, but it can be seen that it is actually a text field (text are left aligned, number are aligned right). Therefore you need ' ' around the value. Second, if you test with a wildcard you must use **LIKE** and not **=**. Third, the SQL wildcard character is **%** (or **_** for a single character). So instead of:

arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management("Vl_lyr", "NEW_SELECTION", ' "NISCODE" = 1* ')

it should be

```
arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management("Vl_lyr", "NEW_SELECTION", """ "NISCODE" LIKE '1%' """)
```

Alternatively, you could use some SQL syntax to take only the first character

```
arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management("Vl_lyr", "NEW_SELECTION", """ LEFT("NISCODE",1) = '1' """)
```

then you can make a loop:

```
mylist = []
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(shp, "NISCODE") as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        mylist.append(row[0])
num_list = list(set(mylist))
for i in num_list:
    arcpy.Select_analysis(shp, shp[:-4] + i +".shp", """ Left("NISCODE",1) = '{}'""".format(i))
```

Note that shp fieldnames must be written between " " , but it would not be the case in gdb.

As a remark, your calculate field expression is not working because 1) you mustn't write the target fiel name in the expression and 2) python field names should be written with ! !.

Answer (score 1):

You could add a new field, and calculate that field based on the field you need. Using python, we can recalculate it to only contain the first digit. It looks like the NISCODE is text so try this:

```
arcpy.AddField_management(shp, "newNISCODE", "TEXT")

arcpy.CalculateField_management(shp, "newNISCODE", '!NISCODE![0]', "PYTHON")

list = []
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(shp, "newNICODE") as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        list.append(row)
new_list = sorted(set(list))
num_list = [item for t in new_list for item in t]

for codenum in num_list:
    arcpy.Select_analysis(shp, 'shp_' + codenum + '.shp',  'newNISCODE' = codenum)
```

Comment: I badly expressed myself I think in my explanation.
So my desired shapefiles should be split based on the first number of the NISCODE, but I still need to have the whole NISCODE in the end.
So I don't need new shapefiles with NISCODE 1,2,3,4,5,6,7; but a shapefile containing all NISCODE's that start with 1, start with 2, and so on...

Comment: This tool is only available at 10.5. I use the Split tool and it works.

Comment: @MacroZED I wanted to comment my adjustments here, but I couldn't use the nice "code layout" here, so it looked like a mess. Therefore I used "answer" to show it.
Where do I have to post my adjustments? Or just edit my first post?

Comment: ive made some edits to the code above.
Add comments here.
Any edits should be made to the original post, at the bottom and make it explicit that its an edit. for example:
EDIT:
.........

Comment: Ok thanks, I'll keep it in mind for future edits/questions :)
I just edited my original post. The script fails on the CalculateField

Comment: I tried to run the script with your new edits (adding the ! marks before and after NISCODE), but the same ERROR 000539 keeps popping up.

Comment: ok try it now. ive changed the expression for calculate field.

Comment: The CalculateField worked now. I checked my attribute table, and a new field "newNISCODE" is created and filled in with number 1,2,3,4,7 (5 and 6 don't exist, so in the end I'll only need 5 shapefiles :))
When starting the loop, the script says to define fc:
NameError: name 'fc' is not defined

Comment: Because youve used FC, instead of shp. change it in the searchcursor

Comment: Ah yes ofcourse. Next he gave a column name error, but that was just due to a type "newNICODE" instead of "newNISCODE".

Now the script struggles over the Select statement:

ExecuteError: ERROR 000358: Invalid expression newNISCODE = "1"
Failed to execute (Select).

Comment: @MacroZED +1, but you should edit your code, because you take the values of the range function instead of the values in the list.

Comment: @AarjenPeeters " " is for shapefile field names, string values must be between ' '. Please take time to check your syntax.

Comment: I added a loop for the numbers in the list. Im sure you know of an easier way @radouxju

Comment: @MacroZED Thanks for your input! 
Now he fails on the output name:

ExecuteError: ERROR 000210: Cannot create output C:\...\shp_(u'1',).shp
ERROR 000354: The name contains invalid characters
Failed to execute (Select).

Comment: @AarjenPeeters I've made a change that hopefully may have solved the problem.

Comment: @MacroZED another error pops up now at the select statement:

TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'tuple' objects

Comment: ok i think ive finally got it. i had to expand the list out to make sure they werent tuples.

Comment: @MacroZED Now this: 
ExecuteError: ERROR 000358: Invalid expression newNISCODE = codenum
Failed to execute (Select).

Comment: @MacroZED no need for double loop here. You can make a single loop on num_list, or a single loop where i is the index of your numlist (for i in range(len(num_list)) ... num_list[i]. then for your last line, codenum has to be a variable (write it out of the ' ' )

Comment: I've just sat here with my sushi and realised that. I've removed the double loop and have made codenum a variable.

Comment: finally, shp is a shapefile with extension .shp, so don't add codenum at the end, otherwise the extension will become invalid (e.g. Adp.shp1). And your quotes are not yet correct...